# How filter TRUE FALSE option in react native firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I make a filter that is Man can see women and women can see men
that mean
user data has ShowMen : true for women user
ShowWomen : true for men user

[image]

when snapshot from firestore
it will return profiles state

```
const [profiles,setProfiles] = useState([]);
 
useEffect(() => {
 
  let unsub;

    
  const fetchCards = async()=>{
      
    unsub = onSnapshot(collection(db,'users'),
    snapshot=>{
      setProfiles(
        snapshot.docs
        .filter(doc=>
         ((doc.id!==user.uid)&&(doc.showMen==true&&doc.gender==='male'))
            || ((doc.id!==user.uid)&&(doc.showWomen==true&&doc.gender==='female'))
         
          )
        .map(
          doc=>({
            id :doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          })
        )
      )
    })//not show already pass/swipe users
  }

  fetchCards();
  return unsub;

}, [])
```

I cannot filter out that I want
doc.id !== user.uid mean authenticated user cannot see his profile view in search list
after that if come data is showMen true and gender female, profile array list result out this and display data
if come data is showWomen true and gender male , profile array result out this and display data

Finally I want is

if user choose ShowMen option true, she will see only men
if user choose ShowWomen option true, he will see only women

How can make this logic in filter()
can someone help me
I need this
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data filtering should be done on the backend level to avoid downloading unnecessary documents.

To make  our life easier, let us redefine our `user` data model as below :

```
{
  s_989777: {
    age: 25,
    displayName: "Roberto Carlos",
    gender: "male",
    interestedIn: "female",
  },

  ab9uyrtt: {
    age: 21,
    displayName: "Christina  Liz",
    gender: "female",
    interestedIn: "male",
  },
};
```

I added new record `interestedIn = [gender]`. this value should be equal to one of `gender`  of existing users. Either `male` or `female`.

With this new data model, we can use Firestore filtering query.

```
import { collection, query, where,getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
const usersRef = collection(db, "users");

// Create a query against the collection.

const interestedIn =  currentUser.interestedIn
const q = query(usersRer, where("gender", "==", interestedIn));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

The result will be array of users with `gender` user is currently interested in

Comment: can you define directly ```const interestedIn =  currentUser.interestedIn``` withut snapshot ,is it undefine?

Comment: `const interestedIn =  currentUser.interestedIn`  assume that when app loaded or user signed in. you load information about that user  and save in global storage or  Async Storage. ` currentUser` is a placeholder for information of the user who is currently using app.

Comment: simply get the answer by your idea.thanks

Comment: Great to hear that. It was one of my first answers on StackOverflow. Ping me for some future Firebase-related issues. In meantime, happy hacking!